# SQL Query Not working when trying to add an INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have an SQL Statement which I finally got working today, Then I wanted to add an INNER JOIN to return my labels instead  of numbers and can't get it to work.

I have three tables port_days, ports and ships

The query that I wrote today is..

```
    SELECT  
        t1.port_day_id, 
        t1.port_id, 
        t1.port_date,
        t1.ship_id,
        t1.arrival_time,
        t1.depart_time
    FROM 
        port_days t1
    WHERE 
        (ship_id = '140' OR ship_id = '145') 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 
                     port_id, port_date
                FROM 
                     port_days t2
                WHERE 
                     (ship_id = '140' OR ship_id = '145') 
                     AND t1.port_date >= '2016-02-01'
                     AND t1.port_date <= '2016-10-01'
                     AND t1. port_id = t2. port_id
                     AND t1. port_date = t2. port_date
                     GROUP BY port_id, port_date
                     HAVING COUNT(port_day_id) > 1)
   ORDER BY port_date
```

So far after testing this seems to return all the correct results like this..

> {"port_day_id":"290","port_id":"1021","port_date":"2016-06-18","ship_id":"140","arrival_time":"06:30:00","depart_time":"16:30:00"}

so now I want to replace the ids for the labels using and `INNER JOIN` and came up with the query below, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
    SELECT  
         s.ship_name,
         s.company_name,
         p.port_name,
         p.port_country,
         t1.port_id, 
         t1.port_date,
         t1.ship_id,
         t1.arrival_time,
         t1.depart_time
    FROM 
        port_days t1
    INNER JOIN  
        ships s, ports p
    ON 
        t1.ship_id = s.ship_id 
        AND t1.port_id = p.port_id 
    WHERE 
        (ship_id = '" . $ship_id . "' OR ship_id = '" . $ship2_id . "') 
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 
                        port_id, port_date
                    FROM 
                        port_days t2
                    WHERE (ship_id = '" . $ship_id . "' 
                        OR ship_id = '" . $ship2_id . "') 
                        AND t1.port_date >= '" . $start_date . "'
                        AND t1.port_date <= '" . $end_date . "'
                        AND t1. port_id = t2. port_id
                        AND t1. port_date = t2. port_date
                        HAVING COUNT(port_day_id) > 1)                         
   ORDER BY port_date)
```

The ship and ports tables hold the ids and labels.

This is what I am hoping to have returned...

> {"port_name":"Southampton",port_country":"England","port_date":"2016-06-18","ship_name":"Arcadia","company_name":"P&O Cruises","arrival_time":"06:30:00","depart_time":"16:30:00"}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) ms sql and mysql are 2 different products. Which one do you use? 2) Is the error message or unexpected behaviour you encountered classified?

Comment: Try describing what you are doing.  There is probably a simpler method for writing the query.

Comment: I think I was lucky that constructs like EXISTS didn't exist (or maybe just weren't used) when I started learning MySQL. Performance issues aside, for a beginner, they just seem to get in the way.

Comment: And don't mix implicit (comma) and explicit JOIN styles. In fact don't use comma-join EVER

Comment: @Shadow i am using mysql sorry for the confusion

Comment: @GordonLinoff What i am trying to is.. I have 2 ship ids, a start date and an end date I want to return the port_days where the port_id and the port_date are the same. I only need the results from the two ship ids. I hoe this makes sense.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and a desired result

Comment: Sorry @Strawberry for my ignorance but I am still very new to SQL and this site can you elaborate on what you need me to provide and i will sort it :-)

Comment: @Strawberry do you mean the table structure?

Comment: CREATE and INSERT statements, and corresponding desired result

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.....

```
SELECT  
     s.ship_name,
     s.company_name,
     p.port_name,
     p.port_country,
     t1.port_id, 
     t1.port_date,
     t1.ship_id,
     t1.arrival_time,
     t1.depart_time
FROM         port_days t1
INNER JOIN   ships     s  ON t1.ship_id = s.ship_id 
INNER JOIN   ports     p  ON t1.port_id = p.port_id 
WHERE  (t1.ship_id = '" . $ship_id . "' OR t1.ship_id = '" . $ship2_id . "') 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 
                    port_id, port_date
                FROM 
                    port_days t2
                WHERE (ship_id = '" . $ship_id . "' 
                    OR ship_id = '" . $ship2_id . "') 
                    AND t1.port_date >= '" . $start_date . "'
                    AND t1.port_date <= '" . $end_date . "'
                    AND t1. port_id = t2. port_id
                    AND t1. port_date = t2. port_date
                    HAVING COUNT(port_day_id) > 1)                         
ORDER BY port_date
```

Comment: just as @mhyst mentioned about splitting the JOIN, I updated my code but it still returns null When i saw your answer I thought that was it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that INNER JOIN works between port_days and ships, there's no sense putting other table fields in the ON section. So if you want to relate other tables, you need a second INNER JOIN.

```
FROM 
    port_days t1
INNER JOIN  
    ships s ON t1.ship_id = s.ship_id 
INNER JOIN ports p ON t1.port_id = p.port_id
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I didn't realise. It make perfect sense to me now .